# Как оптимизировать запрос к БД?

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Вот у меня запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT p.id, p.groupid, p.postid, p.date, p.likes, p.reposts, p.text, p.att1_type, p.att1_data, p.att2_type, p.att2_data, p.att3_type, p.att3_data, p.att4_type, p.att4_data, p.att5_type, p.att5_data, p.att6_type, p.att6_data, p.att7_type, p.att7_data, p.att8_type, p.att8_data, p.att9_type, p.att9_data, p.att10_type, att10_data, g.rating 
    FROM `posts` p 
        JOIN `verified_posts` vp ON p.`id` = vp.`pid` 
        JOIN `grouplists` g ON p.`groupid` = g.`groupid` 
    WHERE g.`usid` = '111' 
        AND vp.`usid` = '111' 
        AND g.`hide` = '0' 
        AND g.`groupid` IN (
            SELECT gid FROM gtags WHERE tid IN ('0','13')
        ) 
    ORDER BY vp.`vdate` DESC 
    LIMIT 40
) AS tmp 
ORDER BY tmp.`rating` DESC
```

Я знаю его слабое место: tid равный 13 в части `g.groupid IN (SELECT gid FROM gtags WHERE tid IN ('0','13'))`– 75 дополнительных строк и именно тут возникает проблема. Раньше всё работало, а вот недавно этот запрос стал выдавать в phpMyAdmin "502 Bad gateway", а php-скрипты вообще выдают 504 ошибку (хотя в настройках php нет ограничения на выполнение). В терминале запрос работает и выдаёт нужные данные.

Я не понимаю что делать. Может вы сталкивались с подобной проблемой или знаете её решение?

P.S. Индексы:
[image: индексы]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38561/discussion-on-question-by-deff-----).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
      SELECT p.id, 
             --
             -- список полей опущен
             --
             g.rating
        FROM gtags gt
        JOIN grouplists g ON gt.gid = g.groupid
        JOIN verified_posts vp ON vp.usid = g.usid
        JOIN posts p ON p.id = vp.pid
       WHERE gt.tid IN (0, 13)
         AND g.usid = 111
         AND g.hide = 0
    ORDER BY vp.vdate DESC
       LIMIT 40
  ) tmp 
ORDER BY tmp.rating DESC
```